# Переместить блок внутри родителя

Tags: jquery

Нужно переместить блок "box1_1" перед блоком "box3_2". Все это должно происходить внутри родителя "content". На данный момент сделал перемещение в блок "box3", но как переместить перед "box3_2"?
Интересует только jQuery. Заранее спасибо.

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="box1"><span class="box1_1"></span></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
    <div class="box3"><span class="box3_1"></span><span class="box3_2"></span></div>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div class="box1"><span class="box1_1"></span></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
    <div class="box3"><span class="box3_1"></span><span class="box3_2"></span></div>
</div>

jQuery( ".content" ).each(function( index ) {
  jQuery(this).find(".box3").prepend(jQuery(this).find(".box1_1"))
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод `.before()`. [Он](https://api.jquery.com/before/) как раз вставляет перед. Ищите нужный элемент и вставляете с помощью `before`.

```js
jQuery( ".content" ).each(function( index ) {
  jQuery(this).find(".box3_2").before(jQuery(this).find(".box1_1"))
});
```

Если надо оставить 1_1 на месте, то используйте `.clone()`:

```js
jQuery( ".content" ).each(function( index ) {
  jQuery(this).find(".box3_2").before(jQuery(this).find(".box1_1").clone())
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь я понял почему у меня такая версия кода не срабатывала. Оказывается блок "box3_1" и блок "box3_2" также подгружаются скриптом. Поэтому "box1_1" не перемещался ( Как этот вопрос решить?

Comment: Сразу скажу, что вариант с jQuery(window).on('load', function() {  не прокатывает ;(

Comment: @VasiliSimanau прикрутить мутацию на изменение элементов